# How do you switch the default input for number/special character keys in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

As the title suggests, I am trying to switch the default number key input to its respective special character. Also I need this to carry over to other special characters like, ".", and ";". In essence when I hit the 1, 2, 3, -, =, [ keys, !, @, #, _, +, or { will be inputted. So it'd be like a permanent shift-lock but rather than capitalizing letters, it'd give me the alternate input for each key.

I was thinking I might have to install a new Language Keyboard Layout, but I couldn't find any that'd do what I need. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want, but if you don't know them already, "*sticky keys*" might fit your needs.

If you haven't changed their settings you should be able to enable them by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> 5 times.

When they're enabled, pressing Shift (or any other modifier) twice in a row will lock it in the "pressed" state.

This makes the number keys output their alternate characters, but it will also affect a lot of other things (e.g. the selection of anything), so it's not really something you can keep enabled all the time.
It's quite quick to switch on and off though, so if you only have this need for a few keystrokes every once in a while it's probably ideal.